# Open Payment Method In New Tab

Tags: expresso-store, ee2, payment-gateway, checkout

I am using PayU discovery miles payment gateway and when the user clicks 'Place your order' on my site I would like to open the discovery page in a new tab. Would this be possible?

The code that I have:

```
{exp:store:payment
    payment_method="PayU"
    form_id="checkout_form3"
    form_name="checkout_form3"
    member_id="CURRENT_USER"
    return="checkout/success/ORDER_HASH"
    <!--secure='yes'-->
}
<button id="checkout_form3_submit_discovery" class="alert" type="submit" name="submit">Place your order</button>

{/exp:store:payment}
```

At the moment, the off-page gateway opens up in the same tab as the website.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a target attribute to the form:

```
{exp:store:payment
   html:target="_blank"
   ...
```

That should do it.